# In SQL, how do you get the column name for largest item in a row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table that has unique id, col1, col2, col3...etc. All of the columns are numeric except the id column. I need to extract for each id, the column with the highest value. So let's say we have an id 1, for which col1 value is 10, col2 value is 20, and col3 value is 30. The result should be two columns. 1 and col3. Basically the id, and the name of the column with the highest value. I hope that is clear.

Comment: Why do you have 30 cols? Why don't you add a col containing 1, .., 30 indicating the col index?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably restructure your data.  Have third repeated columns is a lousy way to store the data.  Traditionally in SQL, you would use a separate table with one row per value.  But BigQuery also supports arrays and JSON formats.

A brute force method uses a giant `case` expression:

```
select t.*,
       (case greatest(col1, col2, col3, . . . )
             when col1 then 'col1'
             when col2 then 'col3'
             . . .
             when col30 then 'col30'
        end) as greatest_value
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the structure of your data is like that but a way around could be like this:

- Use `GREATEST()`, which fetches the largest values from the values that are passed in

```
SELECT
id,
GREATEST(col1,col2,.....col30) AS largest_value

FROM [table name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a union all to put all the columns as the same column and then either get the max or order descing and get the top 1.

Something like this:

```
Select id, (select top 1 name from (
(select id, col1 col, colname name from tablename)
union all
(select id, col2 col, colname name from tablename)
union all
(select id, col3 col, colname name from tablename)
) as t
where t.id = tablename.id 
order by col desc)
from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach with use of UNPIVOT (assumes each row has unique id)

```
select as value array_agg(t order by value desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from (
  select * from `project.dataset.table`
  unpivot (value for col in (col1, col2, col3, col4))
) t
group by id
```

you can test it with below dummy data

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, 11 col1, 12 col2, 13 col3, 14 col4 union all 
  select 2, 24, 23, 22, 21 union all 
  select 3, 31, 34, 32, 33
)
select as value array_agg(t order by value desc limit 1)[offset(0)]
from (
  select * from `project.dataset.table`
  unpivot (value for col in (col1, col2, col3, col4))
) t
group by id
```

with output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option - requires no knowledge of column names so same query can be used no matter how many columns and their names

```
select id, 
  ( select as struct split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] col, 
      cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as numeric) value
    from t.kvs as kv
    order by value desc 
    limit 1
  ).*
from(
  select *, 
    split(translate(to_json_string((select as struct * except(id) from unnest([t]))), '{}"', '')) kvs
  from `project.dataset.table` t
) t
```

You can test with dummy data as in below example

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 id, 11 col1, 12 col2, 13 col3, 14 col4 union all 
  select 2, 24, 23, 22, 21 union all 
  select 3, 31, 34, 32, 33
)
select id, 
  ( select as struct split(kv, ':')[offset(0)] col, 
      cast(split(kv, ':')[offset(1)] as numeric) value
    from t.kvs as kv
    order by value desc 
    limit 1
  ).*
from(
  select *, 
    split(translate(to_json_string((select as struct * except(id) from unnest([t]))), '{}"', '')) kvs
  from `project.dataset.table` t
) t
```

with output

[image]